# Posts cloud - Anyone?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Okay... I turned every stone on the internet and I couldn't find plugin that I need.

I want to have a dedicated page for each tag. When I click on a tag I want to get a page with "posts cloud" - all posts tagged with that tag. Post font should be proportional to "popularity" of a post...

Is there such thing on earth?

Comment: @Daniel Dvorkin asked *How do you measure "Popularity" of a post?* He asked as an answer -- which I deleted -- rather than as a comment, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Don't really have any preference... Any meaningful way of measuring popularity will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at CloudClutter theme and see how its done http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/cloudclutter

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, it should be a plugin... I'm already using a theme that I like.

Comment: Im not telling you to use that theme, just open the themes index.phone and see how its done